# How to Use PdfCrowd Api In codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Hello Iam Using pdfCrowd Api to convert to pdf. If i use convertfile To specify view it says path is not not valid? How to Pass view to pdfCrowd's Convertfile Function?

```html
function download() { require('pdfcrowd.php'); $user_id=$this->session->userdata('user_id'); $data = array(); $data['result']=$this->user_data_model->getcertificate($user_id); try { // create an API client instance $client = new Pdfcrowd('username','api');
// convert a web page and store the generated PDF into a $pdf variable $pdf = $client->convertFile('certificate_template'); // set HTTP response headers header("Content-Type: application/pdf"); header("Cache-Control: max-age=0"); header("Accept-Ranges:
none"); header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"google_com.pdf\""); // send the generated PDF echo $pdf; } catch(PdfcrowdException $why) { echo "Pdfcrowd Error: " . $why; } }
```

```html
function download() { 
         require('pdfcrowd.php');
            $user_id=$this->session->userdata('user_id');
            $data = array();
            $data['result']=$this->user_data_model->getcertificate($user_id);
   
   try
   {   
    // create an API client instance
    $client = new Pdfcrowd('username','api');

    // convert a web page and store the generated PDF into a $pdf variable
    $pdf = $client->convertFile('certificate_template');

    // set HTTP response headers
    header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
    header("Accept-Ranges: none");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"google_com.pdf\"");

    // send the generated PDF 
    echo $pdf;
   }
   catch(PdfcrowdException $why)
   {
    echo "Pdfcrowd Error: " . $why;
   }
  
        
 }
```

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: this is the code.

Comment: re format your question better

Comment: reformat means?

Comment: actually first and second tab code is same. I missed formated initially so i added it again.

Answer (score 0):

convertFile method accepts local HTML file only, it can't be template.

You have 2 options:

- use [convertURI](https://pdfcrowd.com/web-html-to-pdf-php/?show=1#convertURI) with your rendered template instead convertFile

or

- render your template to temporary local HTML file and use it in convertFile method